# Can entity framework core's change tracker detect cascaded child records?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using the ChangeTracker to track all the items that have been marked for deletion. However, I also want to know when a child record has also been deleted as a result of a cascading delete

This is my code.

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var deletedItems = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted);

        foreach (var entity in deletedItems)
        {
            //Log deleted row to external service
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This tells me if Table A has been deleted, but I can't figure out how to get it to tell me which child records have also cascaded.

Any help with this?
Thanks

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? It's not clear to me what I should be looking for in the provided sample of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that cascades do not happen until calling `SaveChanges`.

Suppose that you have two models. `Blog` and `Post`, in which `Blog` has one-to-many relation with `Post`.

When you want to delete a blog record following process will be happened:(for both optional and required relationships when a parent entity is deleted)

1. Blog is marked as Deleted
2. Posts initially remain Unchanged since cascades do not happen until SaveChanges
3. SaveChanges sends deletes for both dependents/children (posts) and then the principal/parent (blog)
4. After saving, all entities are detached since they have now been deleted from the database

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete#entity-deletion-examples

You can check this sample which has a method to log the cascade deleted records:
https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/tree/master/samples/core/Saving/CascadeDelete